# jQuery: How to trim new line and tab characters between words

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am getting new line(\n) and tab(\t) characters between words and I was trying to trim those by using `$.trim()` function but its not working. So can anyone have some solution for this type of problem.

Ex:

```
var str = "Welcome\n\tTo\n\nBeautiful\t\t\t\nWorld";
alert($.trim(str));
```

the above code is not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var str = "Welcome\n\tTo\n\nBeautiful\t\t\t\nWorld";
alert($.trim(str.replace(/[\t\n]+/g,' ')));
// results is  "Welcome To Beautiful World"
```

Comment: Oh... So many answers in quick time but this the perfect one for me. Really its working @palash

Answer (score 18):

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, " "); //try this
```

reference **[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

**\s** matches  any newline or tab or white-space

Comment: IMO this is the best solution. Note that it will also replace duplicate spaces with a single space.

Comment: thanks for focus @PaulDraper it increases my smile :)

Comment: This is nice, since the `+` collapses multiple newlines or tabs into one space.

Comment: This is a good answer but beware if your string contains HTML as this will also remove spaces between tag attributes.

Comment: It is replacing all the occurrences not trimming from left and right side of a string. Does not work in case of trimming. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected. `trim` only takes care of leading and trailing whitespace.

Instead, use

```
str.split(/\s/).join(' ');
```

In your example, this returns

```
"Welcome To Beautiful World"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

```
var str = "Welcome\n\tTo\n\nBeautiful\t\t\t\nWorld";
alert($.trim(str.replace(/[\t\n]+/g, ' ')));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FAsVu/1/)

Comment: It is replacing all the occurrences not trimming from left and right side of a string. Does not work in case of trimming. Thanks.